# mutt attachment with long non-ASCII file name is set to "noname"

Tags: email, filenames, mutt

When I'm attaching a file with Russian name, the recipient received the attachment with name `noname`. I added `set rfc2047_parameters = yes` to .muttrc, and it started to work for simple filenames like `Решение.doc` and `тест тест.txt`. But when I attach a file with a long filename: `Электронный документ, полученный из внешней системы.pdf`, which is still valid and can be attached though Gmail web interface, it still gives `noname` as the file name when sent from mutt.

Is it possible to fix?

Update: locale result:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: What locale setting do you have (the output of the `locale` command)? I tested to send an empty file with the given name to myself with `mutt` (2.0.3) just now, and it worked as expected. I did not set `rfc2047_parameters` at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda Updated the question.

Comment: What email client are the recipient using when they see the `noname` name? What version of `mutt` are you using, and on what operating system?

Comment: @Kusalananda Mutt 1.10.1 (2018-07-13) Linux Slackware 14.2. Seems, that my mutt is outdated, and this is the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* that this is a known bug in older releases of `mutt` and that it was fixed in May 2019 with [commit 6898c083](https://github.com/muttmua/mutt/commit/6898c083). This means that the fix ought to have been included in release 1.12.1.

I'm unable to reproduce your issue with release 2.0.3 (the current release at the time of writing), so I'm assuming that the fix is still in effect.

The issue was that `mutt` truncated the filenames of attachments that had long names.  The truncation was not done correctly for multi-byte character strings and left the last character of the filename encoded erroneously.  When a user's email client noticed that the encoding of the attachment filename was incorrect, it replaced the name with the string `noname`.

After release 1.12.1, you ought to be able to use filenames of up to 255 characters.